# EOF error python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting an EOF error in python 3. Here is my code

```
num = float(input()) #servings
p = float(input()) #people
a2 = float(input())
b2 = float(input())
c2 = float(input())
d2 = float(input())
e2 = float(input())
f2 = float(input())
g2 = float(input())
h2 = float(input())
i2 = float(input())
a1 = a2 / num
b1 = b2 / num
c1 = c2 / num
d1 = d2 / num
e1 = e2 / num
f1 = f2 / num
g1 = g2 / num
h1 = h2 / num
i1 = i2 / num
a = a1 * p
b = b1 * p
c = c1 * p
d = d1 * p
e = e1 * p
f = f1 * p
g = g1 * p
h = h1 * p
i = i1 * p
lis = str(a)+ str(b)+ str(c)+ str(d)+ str(e)+ str(f)+ str(g)+ str(h)+   str(i)
print (lis) #8 14 1 1 6 2 1 2 .5 2
```

and the error is on line 11. If I delete line 11 and all code that goes with it, it gives me the error on line 10, then 9, then 8, etc.

Comment: Can you edit the OP to include all your code? Because sometimes previous code that is incorrect will cause errors later in the code, like if the previous code is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: How are you entering the input to your program?

Comment: Please show the full traceback(s)

Comment: Can't reproduce, when I run the code it works. Are you calling this script programatically and only piping in 10 lines?

Comment: @L3viathan Same here. It works for me, too. What exactly are the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine until you give **11 input values** since there are **11 input statements**. The EOF error occurs when you don't provide sufficient inputs. I assume the **comment on the last line** is your input and it has **only 10 values**. I think that's the reason for the **EOF error**.

Comment: What? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: If you give an empty input ,it shows an EOF error for the input() statement. You can try once.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty input"?

Comment: You have 11 input spaced, and you only have 10 things to put in, so you put in 10 things, but then have an empty spot that it is trying to do math with, but cannot.